# Sort Items in a list box using an array?

Tags: c#

Ok, so i have to sort a listbox (randomListBox) using an array (defaultArray) for university, but the instructions and tutors aren't much help, so this is what i had using the instructions but it doesn't work.

```
    string[] defaultArray = new string[randomListBox.Items.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < randomListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        defaultArray[i] = randomListBox.Items[i].ToString();
    }

    Array.Sort(defaultArray);

    randomListBox.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < randomListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        randomListBox.Items.Add(defaultArray[i].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: what _doesn't_ work ?

Comment: the last line, and when it runs it doesnt put anything back into the listbox

Comment: It doesn't work is not a question. Any error or problem?

Comment: I think if it doesn't work, that is a problem.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second for loop never runs because you have deleted all the items in listbox therefore the items count is `0`. Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < defaultArray.Length; i++)
{
    randomListBox.Items.Add(defaultArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the second occurrence of this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomListBox.Items.Count; i++)
```

Are you sure that's what you meant?

What do you actually want to loop through?

(I'm not providing the answer directly as this is a homework question.)

Answer (score 0):

In the last for loop, you are using randomListBox.Items.Count rather than defaultArray.Length.

```
for (int i = 0; i < defaultArray.Length; i++)
{
    randomListBox.Items.Add(defaultArray[i].ToString());
}
```